# HTML5 canvas clearing and redrawing with for loop

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, for-loop

I'm playing around with JS and found a small HTML5 game tutorial that I thought would be cool to modify. (This is the outcome: http://www.lostdecadegames.com/demos...e_canvas_game/ )

So I modified it just a little bit, letting for loop draw the background. The drawing itself succeed, but something is wrong with it.
I found out that I must clear the canvas and redraw everything to each frame. I did it like this:

```
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

The outcome was that the clearing happened before the loop finished drawing the images.

The cycle is:

- clear canvas
- for loop drawing the background tiles
- draw something else

Somehow it doesn't output the background tiles...

I included my modifications here:
http://jsfiddle.net/swenn/6mWkU/

What might be the problem?

Comment: I can't find your canvas clearing method?

For your run loop it's better to try and use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame). I think the 1 ms delay for the update might be part of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem with your code, you aren't setting your tileY variable back to zero after drawing the floor. This causes the canvas to draw it further and further down, e.g not in the viewspace of the canvas.

```
//Start of your render function.
tileY = 0;
tileX = 0;
```

[Working version, webkit](http://jsfiddle.net/6mWkU/2/)

As I wrote in my comment, you should [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) to schedule your drawing.

You might also want to look into a better way of drawing the floor, maybe making one larger texture and drawing it one time only instead of in a for loop.

EDIT: Fixed the jsfiddle link to actually be the updated version.

Comment: If I set tileY to 0 every time, then it only draws the first row, doesn't it? About the loops: there are 2 of them. One for Y and the other for X. I made them both loop 10 times, so the Y cannot loop forever. Also, the included link seems to be same as mine.

Comment: Yes if you do it at the end of the first for loop, but you should be setting it just before the first for loop starts. At the top of the render function.

Comment: Both of them are actually set to 0 in the upper part of the code.

Comment: The upper most part of the code is only ran once, you need to set it each time the render function runs because the clearRect method clears everything and that includes the floor. See my updated fiddle.

Comment: Ohw. I got it now. Thanks for your help. :)